# White flicker after Phonegap 5.1 splashscreen

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using `PhoneGap 5.1.1`.

By default, it loads the `splashscreen` in native mode. But when the splash-screen hides, then the web elements load with a white flicker and sometimes they are loaded as if they are adjusting to fit the screen.

How can I eliminate this flicker and directly show the fully loaded home screen of the app as soon as the splash-screen disappears?